# server.htmlencode of asp.net equivalent in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a ASP.NET MVC controller which is making call to another service using HttpClient class.

```
             var url = "some url";
             var client = new HttpClient();
             var result= client.GetAsync(url);
```

The URL I am sending contains some special characters. How can encode special characters in ASP.NET MVC controller?

Thanks!!1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
url = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are considering a URL that will be used as such for a request (with `HttpClient.getAsync`) -- not as an argument within another URL -- you should use [`Uri.EscapeUriString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapeuristring.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1).

Here is a comparison of three methods for the following URL:

```
var url = "http://some url?data=x y+z&user=1#ok";
```

#### [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Console.WriteLine(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url));
```

> http%3a%2f%2fsome+url%3fdata%3dx+y%2bz%26user%3d1%23ok

Obviously, this is not desired: the URL got damaged with `/` escaped, a `+` entered in the path, ...etc. The method seems useful for the query part of the URL, but not for the whole lot.

#### [HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlpathencode(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Console.WriteLine(HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(url));
```

> http://some%20url?data=x y+z&user=1#ok

This looks useful, although the space is a bit of a problem in the query part (notice the broken hyperlinking here, although browser can deal with it). But more importantly, the method is being deprecated:

> Do not use; intended only for browser compatibility. Use `UrlEncode`.

#### [Uri.EscapeUriString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Console.WriteLine(Uri.EscapeUriString(url));
```

> http://some%20url?data=x%20y+z&user=1#ok

This seems to do the job well: `%20` is an escape sequence that all modern browsers should support, also when occurring in the query part of the URL.

Answer (score -1):

There is no need it encoding in Razor View Engine starting from 3rd version, and it's very convenient. Instead if you want to use tags you should use:

```
@Html.Raw(myString)
```

So basically just using Razor comes with encoding by default.

Comment: Thank you for reply. But I am not using any view. Instead from my controller I am making call to another service.

Comment: @Brown_Dynamite Ok, you asked for utility in asp.net mvc, that's why I've decided you are using views. Then use `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` instead of UrlEncode, because it suits `server.htmlencode` better. Just add proper reference to project.

Answer (score -1):

You should use HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode

When you use url = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url) it doesn't work fine with spaces.

Comment: This answer goes against the instruction on the [documentation page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlpathencode(v=vs.110).aspx): ***"Do not use; intended only for browser compatibility. Use UrlEncode."***. Please consider removing your answer so people do not get misinformed.

Comment: Did you have a chance to test it? When i used UrlEncode i had a problems with spaces. For example: "Test Body" was encoded as Test+Body. But UrlPathEncoed works as expected. Please try to test it @trincot